# @vanilla-extract/css - is there a way to export stylesheet CSS for shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stitches, vanilla-extract

I am looking at `@vanilla-extract/css` for my styling in React app. The method `style` exports a className from the `*.css.ts` file but I require inline styling for Shadow DOM encapsulation.

I was checking `@stitches/react` it provides a way called `createCss` were a `css` is a named export of the method.

I don't see any similar methods in `@vanilla-extract/css`.

```
export const sprinkles = createSprinkles(
  responsiveProperties,
  colorProperties
);

export const appStyle = sprinkles({
  display: 'flex',
  paddingTop: 'small',
  backgroundColor: 'red'
});

console.log(appStyle) // => gives obfuscated css classname `_1jbh1078`
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

Though the question remains valid, but I have moved forward with `@stitches/react` at this point. See my answer for `@stitches/react` way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@vanilla-extract/css` doesn't give a way to export CSS. But `@stitches/css` has done a good job with some caveats.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createStitches } from '@stitches/react';

const { styled, getCssText, css } = createStitches({
  theme: {
    colors: {
      red: '#F00',
      blue: 'blue'
    }
  }
});

const box = css({
  background: '$red',
  color: '$blue'
});

const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('root');

const shadowRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  element.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
);

shadowRoot.render(<><div className={box()}>App Colored</div><style>{getCssText()}</style></>);
```

1. The `getCssText` extracts all the style sheets from the config and puts it under `<style />` tags - The issue here is `stitches/react` has no ways to tree shaking unwanted variables.
2. The `<style>` tag in the Shadow DOM should only be placed after all the `css` functions are consumed.